# Populate QTableWidgetItem with numbers (int, float,...) from database

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt

I am trying to fill a table in my application with data from a database (postgresql).
If the data is only strings it works just fine, but if it's ints the table stays empty.

My code looks like the following:

```
                    self.ui.tableWidget_employees.setRowCount(5)
                    tablerow = 0
                    sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM test3"

                    cur.execute(sqlquery)

                    records = cur.fetchall()

                    for r in records:
                        self.ui.tableWidget_employees.setItem(
                            tablerow, 0, QTableWidgetItem(r[3])
                        )

                        tablerow += 1
```

This works just fine, if the data in the columns is a string. If I take a column with int as datatype it isn't displaying anything. If I print(r) it shows the content of the database correctly.
To make sure it's not the data from the database I tried to populate it with an int from a variable but that doesn't work either.

```
                    self.ui.tableWidget_employees.setRowCount(5)
                    tablerow = 0
                    test1 = 12558
                    sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM test3"

                    self.ui.tableWidget_employees.setItem(
                        tablerow, 0, QTableWidgetItem(test1)
                    )
```

Is it possible to populate QTableWidgets with integers? If yes what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [QTableWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#QTableWidgetItem) constructor has an overload that specifies the item's [type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#type) (which happens to be an `int`). You therefore need to either convert the value to a `str`, or use [setData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData) instead (which will preserve the original value as an `int`).